# How deep is the frost line for footers in Michigan?

Tags: foundation

How deep is the frost line for footers in Michigan? I want to put in a small shed in the back yard. 200 square feet large.

Comment: Where at in Michigan ... big state running North/South. I'm sure up North it's going to be a bit deeper than down at the bottom of the lakes.

Comment: SW Michigan close to Grand rapids

Answer (score 2):

Historically, the frost line has been 42" in Leelanau county, in northern Michigan (http://www.leelanau.cc/howdoia.asp?rid=12).  But with the severe cold spells in the past couple of years, where even southerly Kalamazoo, frost has reached down 5 feet in some places, MI municipal code officials may adjust that number downward one day soon.